# Countdown Timer Field cannot find Countdown Timer Library - even though it's there

Tags: entities

I'm facing trouble with the enabling of the "Countdown Timer Field" module from within "Administrator" -> "Modules" -> Fields. 
The error message I get is

> "The jQuery Countdown Timer Library could not be found. Please download it, install it in a libraries directory, and rename the directory to jquery-countdown. The library should be available at a path like sites/all/libraries/jquery-countdown/assets/countdown/jquery.countdown.js (Currently using jQuery Countdown Timer Library Not found)".

This doesn't really make sense to me, since I unzipped the JQuery in the correct location (I think.)

This is part of the "JQuery Coundown" module, version 7.x-1.0-alpha1. My end goal is to use Views on a field with a Countdown.

This is my directory structure:

```
root@brian-VirtualBox:/var/www/drupal/sites/all/libraries/jquery-countdown/assets/countdown# ls -laSh
total 16K
drwx------ 2 root root 4.0K Dec 30  2011 .
drwx------ 6 root root 4.0K Dec 30  2011 ..
-rwx------ 1 root root 3.0K Dec 29  2011 jquery.countdown.js
-rwx------ 1 root root 1.7K Dec 29  2011 jquery.countdown.css
root@brian-VirtualBox:/var/www/drupal/sites/all/libraries/jquery-countdown/assets/countdown#
```

Opening up index.html located in /var/www/drupal/sites/all/libraries/jquery-countdown/index.html works on my browser.

This looks like a permissions error.

```
root@brian-VirtualBox:/var/www/drupal/sites/all/libraries# chmod -R 777 jquery-countdown/
```

Then, the module will install correctly. However, I do **NOT** think 777 is a good permission to use on this, so I'm continuing to read about Drupal 7 Libraries, and what permissions should be used. It looks like the .zip I unziped did not preserve the correct file permissions for jquery-countdown.

More specifically, my question has now become, what should the permissions be for directories in sites/all/libraries for Libraries 7.x-20?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The permissions were wrong after unzipping. They should have been:

```
 drwxr-xr-x 4 www-data www-data
```

which can be accomplished by:

```
 chmod 755 -R jquery-countdown/
```